# Explanation of metallic crystal structures using orbitals and electron configuration

Tags: orbitals, metal, electronic-configuration, crystal-structure, crystallography

There has to be a direct relation between metallic crystal structure formation and electrons in orbitals. For instance, we know that **Fe<sup>2+</sup>** forms *body centered cubic* or *bcc* structure with the coordination number of 8, which means each Fe atom bonds with 8 others after getting rid of the two electrons in the 4S orbital.

The electron configuration of one Fe<sup>2+</sup> would look as follows:

1s<sup>2</sup>  2s<sup>2</sup>2p<sup>6</sup>  3s<sup>2</sup>3p<sup>6</sup>3d<sup>6</sup>

The problem is, that I do not see how Fe<sup>2+</sup> would react with 8 others, based on the electron configuration and the octet rule, to form bcc structure.

Comment: $\ce{Fe^2+}$ might form virtually any crystal structure depending on the anionic part. And no, there is no *direct* relationship between the electronic configuration of a single atom and the crystal structure it takes a part of (at least, I'm not aware of any).

Comment: I second that. There is no relation.

Comment: @IvanNeretin maybe I should rephrase that. I mean the relation between the electronic configuration and coordination number, because there is a direct one.

Comment: @andselisk what do you mean the anionic part? I'm talking about metallic bond of pure iron. I need the relation between the electronic configuration and coordination number. From that I can guess the crystal structure.

Comment: @vahidseo There is one, but it is applicable to coordination compounds and **not** to pure metals.

Comment: @vahidseo Pure iron doesn't consist of $\ce{Fe^2+}$. Crystal structure of a material is a property of a neutral substance, hence there must be an anionic part.

Comment: @andselisk I'm not taking about just Fe2+. The two extra electrons are still there. It's a metallic bond.

Comment: @IvanNeretin could you please redirect me to a scientific paper or article, which discusses this matter?

Comment: There is no matter and nothing to discuss. You can't look at the electronic structure and deduce crystal structure, period. Then again, you may find a good deal of papers on crystal structure prediction, but they deal with the subject at an entirely different complexity level.

Comment: In solid state physics, generally one does not care a whole lot about the atomic electronic structure.